# Java Cambiar Texto por asteriscos en JOptionPane

Tags: java, javafx

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente codigo que pide una contraseña pero quiero que se vean en asteriscos en lugar de lo que escribo.

```
@FXML
public void pedirPass() {
    String pass = "root";
    String dialogpass;
    try {
        dialogpass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Contraseña Administrador:");

        if (dialogpass.isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Pass");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error");
            alert.setContentText("No has escrito nada!");

            alert.showAndWait();
        } else if (dialogpass.equals(pass)) {
            System.out.println("Entraste");

        } else {
            dialogpass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Escriba nuevamente la contraseña", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            if (dialogpass.equals(pass)) {
                txt_KmIni.setDisable(false);
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
                alert.setTitle("Control Vehicular");
                alert.setHeaderText("ATENCION, Consulte con el Administrador");
                alert.setContentText("Vulva a intentarlo con la contraseña correcta!");

                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola Riddick!
El método ***showInputDialog( )*** de la clase **JOptionPane** permite crear diálogos para ingreso de datos de forma sencilla, sin embargo, para realizar lo que quieres es necesario crear un diálogo personalizable, fácilmente podrías hacerlo agregando un **JPasswordField** en lugar de la cadena de texto y luego obteniendo el arreglo de caracteres ingresados para proceder con la comprobación de la contraseña.

Para obtener los caracteres escritos en el **JPasswordField**, puedes utilizar:

```
new String(contraseña.getPassword());
```

Por ejemplo:

```
JPasswordField contraseña = new JPasswordField();
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, contraseña, "Ingrese contraseña", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    dialogpass = new String(contraseña.getPassword());
    // Haces la comprobación de la contraseña
}
```

Comment: Gracias C. Rodriguez.  Busque algo similar pero no lo hacia funcionar correctamente.  Fue de mucha ayuda Saludos!

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que te ha servido! Fue un placer :)